# SQL: Multiple between values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to select the name of some cities. I have their area code and in my database, I have all cities with a area code interval. I'm trying to select multiple cities from MySQL, but I cannot figure out how.

I've tried this query

```
SELECT name FROM cities WHERE ('8382', '8000') BETWEEN zip_min AND zip_max
```

Where 8382 and 8000 is two area codes. I would expect the output

```
Hinnerup
Aarhus C
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d369da

Comment: Please amend your question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two individual `WHERE` clauses:

```
SELECT name 
FROM cities 
WHERE '8382' BETWEEN zip_min AND zip_max
OR '8000' BETWEEN zip_min AND zip_max
```

Comment: The situation is that the amount of zip codes can vary. I can expect up to 100 zip codes. That'll be a hell of a SQL query. There must be some way to get past this.

Comment: Big queries happen. It's one of many truths in programming.

Comment: You could loop on your input data an query once for each code.

Comment: Okay then, I'll proceed with the big query!